# Find specific table row containing substring text of a jquery variable of html

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have a jquery object called `$(stuff)`.

Inside `$(stuff)` is a bunch of html code containing a variable number of `<table>`s and I want to take a look at just that first table in the html.

Inside this first table I want to search the first column(or really any column) to find a substring with a value of "9.5"

I want to know how many rows down "9.5" is in that table and return that value.

**Idea of code to perform the operation(does NOT work):**

```
                var tableRow = $(stuff).filter(function () {
                    return $('td' + ":contains(9.5)");
                }).closest("tr");
```

Comment: You can use `$(stuff).find( "table:first tr:contains(9.5)");` if you are more specific to find the text only in first table .

Comment: Can you provide some sample code of table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to make it more complex simply do as follows.

```
var tableRow = $(stuff).find("tr:contains(9.5)");
```

---

More specific one using **[`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)** pseudo-class selector.

```
var tableRow = $(stuff).find("tr:has(td:contains(9.5))");
```

Comment: I put `alert(tableRow);` as the next line to see what the returned number is. It returns "[Object object]" in the alertbox. What gives?

Comment: @user1869407 :  which returns the jQuery object.... get the text using  `alert(tableRow.text())`